# SpriteKit objective c node movement only on x axis

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, objective-c-blocks, skspritenode

I am making simple game using SriteKit, where ball just bounce up and down, and when it comes down you need to put board under so ball bounce back, for now i can put board anywhere on screen, but i want to put in specific y axis, so board can only move in x axis. My question are: what i do wrong and what i need to change, so it works how i want it?
P.S Sorry for my bad English.

Here are a lil bit of my code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"board"];
        sprite.xScale = 0.5; 
        sprite.yScale = 0.5;
        sprite.position = location; 
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.frame.size];  
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

        SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:2];    
        SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];      
        SKAction *actionSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[delay,remove]];      
        [sprite runAction:actionSequence];
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
}
```

Comment: What I am seeing here, is you put a sprite on the screen, it does nothing, then dissapears,  is that what is currently happening?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ball bounces on that board, its like ping pong game only difference is that you don't need to slide board with your finger just tap

Comment: yup, I provided you an answer,  you touch anywhere on the x, the paddle shows up at the touch x location, specified y location

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you very much, now it works like I want it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to is set the location via the y axis

```
CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(touchlocation.x,100);  //where 100 is the spot on the y axis you want to stay on
```